# Why am i getting Invalid matrix id while retrieving the calculated matrix in routing api v8 of here maps?

Tags: routes, here-api, heremaps

I'm getting the following error, when i try to get the matrix details of the following matrix with id 0d0762ee-916d-4eb1-8254-cb80fad7eb89.

The id is the same returned from the POST request, but it says that it's invalid.

{u'status': 404, u'code': u'E601108', u'title': u'invalid HTTP request', u'action': u'Check that the provided matrix ID is valid.', u'cause': u'unknown matrix ID', u'correlationId': u'c81c5abd-ab00-4597-8ce4-11b33e7d645c'}